# how to add the github icon in jupyter notebook

Tags: git, github, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to add the github icon in my all Jupyter notebooks.I have already installed github on Windows. I found the following link and I tried to implement it:

https://github.com/sat28/githubcommit

When I run:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/getamu/githubcommit.git
```

I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\amuly>pip install git+https://github.com/getamu/githubcommit.git
Collecting git+https://github.com/getamu/githubcommit.git
  Cloning https://github.com/getamu/githubcommit.git to c:\users\amuly\appdata\local\temp\pip-fuog0w-build
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\amuly\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-fuog0w-build\\setup.py'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\amuly\appdata\local\temp\pip-fuog0w-build\
```

Answer (score 2):

**Commit-and-Push to GitHub from Jupyter Notebooks (Windows installation)**

*Please convert to RHEL OS if needed*.

1. Install python 2.7 based on your OS. Now install Anaconda.
2. Open CMD,  change directory to `C:`
3. Locate python installation. Copy the entire path of the script directory.
4. Go back to CMD and cd, paste in the entire path of the script directory and hit enter
5. After entry, type dir, hit enter
6. Type `pip3 install jupyter` press enter. This will install the Jupyter Notebook.
7. `CD..` back to the script directory
8. Type `jupyter notebook` hit enter. This will launch Jupyter Notebook.  (Waa-Laa)
9. Open a new command prompt, drill down to `C:\Program Files\Python27\Scripts>`
10. Run `pip install git+https://github.com/sat28/githubcommit.git` (Enter)
11. Run `C:\Program Files\Python27\Scripts>jupyter serverextension enable --py githubcommit`
12. Run `C:\Program Files\Python27\Scripts>jupyter nbextension install --py githubcommit`
13. To initialize this nbextension in the browser every time the notebook (or other app) loads:  Run `C:\Program Files\Python29\Scripts>jupyter nbextension enable githubcommit –py`
14. Refresh or restart the Jupyter Notebook. You will then see the GIT ICON.

https://youtu.be/o6aOqkmrrb4